# Adding styles to an element when another element later in the source is hovered

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div>some texts</div>
<span>
    something
    <a href="#">link</a>
</span>
<img src="#" height='35' width='35' />
```

I'm trying to change the color of that link `<a>` when user goes on that image `<img>`. *(goes on that element = `:hover`)*. Noted that this doesn't work:

```
img:hover a {
    color: red;
}
```

Doing that is possible?

---

If doing what I want in above isn't possible, what about this HTMM structure?

```
<a><img src="#" height='35' width='35' /></a>
<div>
    some texts
    <span><a href="#">link</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

In this case I want to change the color of that inner `<a>` when user goes on that image `<img>` *(:hover)*.

Comment: var doc = document;
    var div = doc.getElementsByTagName('div');
    var anchor = doc.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var img = doc.getElementsByTagName('img');

    img[0].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
      anchor[0].style.color = "red";
    });

    img[0].addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
      anchor[0].style.color = "blue";
    });

Comment: @RonRoyston Actually I don't want to do that by JS .. thank you anyway.

Comment: ...just curious, why not?

Comment: @RonRoyston Because if JS be deactivate on the user's browser, then my website design will be damaged.. In other word the CSS is broken.

Comment: <noscript>
                <strong>Warning !</strong>
                Because your browser does not support HTML5, some elements are created using JavaScript.
                Unfortunately your browser has disabled scripting. Please enable it in order to display this page.
            </noscript>